C++ Win32 Compression API will not extract with Extraction Wizard
Visual Studio C++ compression API compiles, and compresses a single file successfully, and uncompressing the file with Extraction Wizard give the error in the attached screengrab: 
Am I missing something to compress the single file correctly so that decompression will work in File Explorer?
Thanks for you help.
Windows 11
Visual Studio C++ 2022
Desktop Target
Intel Core i9
Code from Windows website: Using the Compression API in buffer mode was used, and a jpg (HDMI.jpg) was compressed using code to create a zipped file called Myzip.zip. The input file size was 104269 bytes, and the compressed size decreased to 100676.
I expected that unzipping the file would create an uncompressed file called HDMI.jpg, and instead I received the error Cannot Complete the Compressed (zipped) Folders Extraction Wizard The compressed (zipped) folder is empty. Before you can extract files, you must copy files to this compressed (zipped) folder.
There is a WriteFile function, which seemed successful. This was tried in both Debug (x64) mode and Release (x64) mode. Running the final program in the IDE or the Command Prompt provided the same issue. I also tried to use different algorithms such as COMPRESS_ALGORITHM_XPRESS_HUFF and COMPRESS_ALGORITHM_MSZIP in the parameter for CreateCompressor and all had the same error when extracting.
An uncompressed jpg file was tried, and a txt file was also tried, both with the same error when attempting to unzip.
Also tried 7-zip and it had the same error.
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <compressapi.h>

void wmain(_In_ int argc, _In_ WCHAR* argv[])
{
    COMPRESSOR_HANDLE Compressor = NULL;
    PBYTE CompressedBuffer = NULL;
    PBYTE InputBuffer = NULL;
    HANDLE InputFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    HANDLE CompressedFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    BOOL DeleteTargetFile = TRUE;
    BOOL Success;
    SIZE_T CompressedDataSize, CompressedBufferSize;
    DWORD InputFileSize, ByteRead, ByteWritten;
    LARGE_INTEGER FileSize;
    ULONGLONG StartTime, EndTime;
    double TimeDuration;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        wprintf(L"Usage:\n\t%s <input_file_name> <compressd_file_name>\n", argv[0]);
        return;
    }

    //  Open input file for reading, existing file only.
    InputFile = CreateFile(
        argv[1],                  //  Input file name
        GENERIC_READ,             //  Open for reading
        FILE_SHARE_READ,          //  Share for read
        NULL,                     //  Default security
        OPEN_EXISTING,            //  Existing file only
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,    //  Normal file
        NULL);                    //  No attr. template

    if (InputFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        wprintf(L"Cannot open \t%s\n", argv[1]);
        goto done;
    }

    //  Get input file size.
    Success = GetFileSizeEx(InputFile, &FileSize);
    if ((!Success) || (FileSize.QuadPart > 0xFFFFFFFF))
    {
        wprintf(L"Cannot get input file size or file is larger than 4GB.\n");
        goto done;
    }
    InputFileSize = FileSize.LowPart;

    //  Allocate memory for file content.
    InputBuffer = (PBYTE)malloc(InputFileSize);
    if (!InputBuffer)
    {
        wprintf(L"Cannot allocate memory for uncompressed buffer.\n");
        goto done;
    }

    //  Read input file.
    Success = ReadFile(InputFile, InputBuffer, InputFileSize, &ByteRead, NULL);
    if ((!Success) || (ByteRead != InputFileSize))
    {
        wprintf(L"Cannot read from \t%s\n", argv[1]);
        goto done;
    }

    //  Open an empty file for writing, if exist, overwrite it.
    CompressedFile = CreateFile(
        argv[2],                  //  Compressed file name
        GENERIC_WRITE | DELETE,     //  Open for writing; delete if cannot compress
        0,                        //  Do not share
        NULL,                     //  Default security
        CREATE_ALWAYS,            //  Create a new file; if exist, overwrite it
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,    //  Normal file
        NULL);                    //  No template

    if (CompressedFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        wprintf(L"Cannot create file \t%s\n", argv[2]);
        goto done;
    }

    //  Create an XpressHuff compressor.
    Success = CreateCompressor(
        COMPRESS_ALGORITHM_XPRESS_HUFF, //  Compression Algorithm
        NULL,                           //  Optional allocation routine
        &Compressor);                   //  Handle

    if (!Success)
    {
        wprintf(L"Cannot create a compressor %d.\n", GetLastError());
        goto done;
    }

    //  Query compressed buffer size.
    Success = Compress(
        Compressor,                  //  Compressor Handle
        InputBuffer,                 //  Input buffer, Uncompressed data
        InputFileSize,               //  Uncompressed data size
        NULL,                        //  Compressed Buffer
        0,                           //  Compressed Buffer size
        &CompressedBufferSize);      //  Compressed Data size

    //  Allocate memory for compressed buffer.
    if (!Success)
    {
        DWORD ErrorCode = GetLastError();

        if (ErrorCode != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            wprintf(L"Cannot compress data: %d.\n", ErrorCode);
            goto done;
        }

        CompressedBuffer = (PBYTE)malloc(CompressedBufferSize);
        if (!CompressedBuffer)
        {
            wprintf(L"Cannot allocate memory for compressed buffer.\n");
            goto done;
        }
    }

    StartTime = GetTickCount64();

    //  Call Compress() again to do real compression and output the compressed
    //  data to CompressedBuffer.
    Success = Compress(
        Compressor,             //  Compressor Handle
        InputBuffer,            //  Input buffer, Uncompressed data
        InputFileSize,          //  Uncompressed data size
        CompressedBuffer,       //  Compressed Buffer
        CompressedBufferSize,   //  Compressed Buffer size
        &CompressedDataSize);   //  Compressed Data size

    if (!Success)
    {
        wprintf(L"Cannot compress data: %d\n", GetLastError());
        goto done;
    }

    EndTime = GetTickCount64();

    //  Get compression time.
    TimeDuration = (EndTime - StartTime) / 1000.0;

    //  Write compressed data to output file.
    Success = WriteFile(
        CompressedFile,     //  File handle
        CompressedBuffer,   //  Start of data to write
        CompressedDataSize, //  Number of byte to write
        &ByteWritten,       //  Number of byte written
        NULL);              //  No overlapping structure

    if ((ByteWritten != CompressedDataSize) || (!Success))
    {
        wprintf(L"Cannot write compressed data to file: %d.\n", GetLastError());
        goto done;
    }

    wprintf(
        L"Input file size: %d; Compressed Size: %d\n",
        InputFileSize,
        CompressedDataSize);
    wprintf(L"Compression Time(Exclude I/O): %.2f seconds\n", TimeDuration);
    wprintf(L"File Compressed.\n");

    DeleteTargetFile = FALSE;

done:
    if (Compressor != NULL)
    {
        CloseCompressor(Compressor);
    }

    if (CompressedBuffer)
    {
        free(CompressedBuffer);
    }

    if (InputBuffer)
    {
        free(InputBuffer);
    }

    if (InputFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        CloseHandle(InputFile);
    }

    if (CompressedFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        //  Compression fails, delete the compressed file.
        if (DeleteTargetFile)
        {
            FILE_DISPOSITION_INFO fdi;
            fdi.DeleteFile = TRUE;      //  Marking for deletion
            Success = SetFileInformationByHandle(
                CompressedFile,
                FileDispositionInfo,
                &fdi,
                sizeof(FILE_DISPOSITION_INFO));
            if (!Success) {
                wprintf(L"Cannot delete corrupted compressed file.\n");
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(CompressedFile);
    }
}


It looks you only write compressed data but ZIP file is expected to provide files metadata like file name, file size, CRC checksum etc. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#File_headers

Thank you @dewaffled, I will look into the metadata.

Win32 APIs do not provide way to create zip format files.
You need to use third-party library or create the format by yourself.
Maybe similar: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=net-6.0

To use the ZipFile class in a .NET Framework app, you must add a
reference to the System.IO.Compression.FileSystem assembly in your
project.


Use .NET API in C++CLR.

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace System;
using namespace  System::IO;
using namespace  System::IO::Compression;

System::String^ StdStringToUTF16(std::string s)
{

    cli::array<System::Byte>^ a = gcnew cli::array<System::Byte>(s.length());
    int i = s.length();
    while (i-- > 0)
    {
        a[i] = s[i];
    }

    return System::Text::Encoding::UTF8->GetString(a);
}
int main()
{
    
    std::string startPath = "FolderName";
    String^ zipPath = ".\\result1.zip";
    String^ extractPath = ".\\extract";
    ZipFile::CreateFromDirectory(StdStringToUTF16(startPath), zipPath);
    ZipFile::ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
    return 0;
}


Thank you minxin-yu-msft. I will attempt to manually create the zip format, and will also use your .NET solution. This question is marked as answered.
